# How to make last line the first (the top) of the terminal?

Tags: shell, command-line

I have a mac, and for improved readibility, sometimes I `clear` the terminal. I'd like to know if there's a shorcut to make the last line become the first of the terminal without clearing anything in the terminal.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still able to scroll up after `clear`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this?

```
clear;tail -1 file
```